LyX fails to process svg when exporting pdf
I have LyX 2.4.1 installed in Fedora 40, and have some SVG graphics created with Inkscape. I added this converter

to LyX. Still, when I export to PDF it fails with this message:


A converter should have been found by default. Did you get an error before adding the converter?

Also, the converter that LyX uses for inkscape-based SVG conversion would be something like the following: inkscape $$i --export-area-drawing --export-filename=$$o which is different from yours.

There was a default converter, which was working, but the output was a pixelated image instead of vector. I guess the default one is the one called "SVG -> PDFTEX" which has the command $${python} $$s/scripts/svg2pdftex.py  $$p$$i $$p$$o.

@scottkosty I tried modifying my "SVG -> PDF (graphics)" converter to inkscape $$i --export-area-drawing --export-filename=$$o but it is the same.

By the way, Inkscape works fine from the command line. For example, inkscape --export-area-page -o deleteme.pdf drawing.svg does what it is expected to do.

Ah interesting. I think I've seen reports of that before. I'm not sure why inkscape isn't prioritized in that case. Might be an issue reporting at lyx-users or lyx-devel mailing list or https://www.lyx.org/trac. I think vector conversion should be preferred, but I forget if there was a reason LyX needed to do that.
